# Struct allocation issue

Tags: c

What is the difference between this 3 ? are basically the same ?

```
 struct X* x = (struct X*)malloc(sizeof(struct X));
 
    struct X* x = (struct X*)malloc(sizeof(x)); 
       
    struct X* x = (struct X*)malloc(sizeof *x);
```

Comment: Second one only allocates bytes for the pointer

Comment: Side note: it's best [not to cast the return from `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/10077).

Comment: `struct X* x = (struct X*)malloc(sizeof(struct X));` --> Most work.  `struct X* x = (struct X*)malloc(sizeof(x));` --> wrong.  `struct X* x = (struct X*)malloc(sizeof *x);` --> better.  `struct X* x = malloc(sizeof *x);` --> best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not the same:

1. `sizeof(struct X)` allocates space using the `struct X` definition.
2. `sizeof(x)` allocates space based on the size of `x`.  `x` is a *pointer* to `struct X`, and pointers will most likely be 4 or 8 bytes depending on your system.
3. `sizeof *x` allocates space based on the size of `*x`, whose type is an object of `struct X`.  Therefore, this allocates the same amount of space as 1.^

2 is incorrect.  When allocating memory, you want to allocate space for "one level up".  In this case, `x` is a `struct X*` type, so you must allocate enough space for a `struct X` object.  1 and 3 both do this.  Of these, 3 is generally considered the preferred practice because it requires less maintenance.  Consider later down the road, you decide to use a new structure here, `struct myNewStruct* x`.  For 1, you would also have to change the amount of requested memory to `malloc(sizeof(myNewStruct))`.  If using 3, you have no extra work to do, because now `*x` is a `struct myNewStruct` type, feeding the correct size to `malloc` "automatically".  Also note that for similar reasons, [casting the return result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) is bad practice, as you would also need to change your cast from `(struct X*)` to `(struct myNewStruct*)`.

```
// This will compile and work, but see how many things have to change
// if your struct type ever changes? Three changes are required
struct myNewStruct* x = (struct myNewStruct*)malloc(sizeof(struct myNewStruct));

// as opposed to this, where only one change is needed
struct myNewStruct* x = malloc(sizeof *x);
```

---

^It's important to note that `sizeof` is almost always [evaluated at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179592/does-sizeof-evaluate-at-compile-time-or-runtime/11179647#11179647) (only exception being VLAs I think), and the size of the type of the operand is what's evaluated.

Comment: As a note for understanding the C standard and technical specifications in general: `sizeof *x` **cannot** allocate space based on the object `x` points to, because `x` does not point anywhere at this point in the code—it does not have a value. Suppose we wrote `x = NULL; printf("%zu\n", sizeof *x);`. Here there is definitely no object that `x` points to, yet `sizeof` gives us the size we expect. The way this is written in the C standard is that `sizeof` determines the size from the **type** of the operand. The type of the expression `*x` is `struct X`, regardless of whether `x` has a value.

Comment: @EricPostpischil very important clarification, I will work that into the answer.